# Optimizing XGBClassifier for discrimination power

Tags: classification, boosting, loss-functions, unbalanced-classes, ranking

I am developing a credit risk decisioning model, i.e. a model that assesses the risk of default of an incoming transactions and decides whether to accept it or not. Of course my dataset is imbalanced : the minority class (i.e. defaulted transactions) represents ~5% of my data.
What I care about is discrimination power rather than good probabilities because I will use the model to make decisions given an acceptance rate target (e.g. I want to accept 90% of incoming transactions), not to make financial predictions (in which case well calibrated probabilities would be important).
Because of that, I evaluate my model with ROC AUC (or PR AUC, I am still unsure which would be best). However, I saw that even though I evaluate my model with AUC, I should still keep binary:logistic as the objective function of my XGBClassifier. The reasons to me are unclear why, but one difficulty I can foresee with having an "AUC objective function" is that it's not possible to define a loss function (and let alone a differentiable one) that would give the "AUC loss" of one given sample as AUC is an aggregate loss rather than an individual one, and I understand that XGB needs an individual loss to compute the losses at the leaf level.

Knowing that, it means that the only way to optimize my model for discrimination power is to use AUC as an evaluation metric in the process of hyperparameter optimization. I find that quite disappointing because as per my experience, hyper-param optimization is not a real game changer and usually only allows to earn a few basis points of AUC.

Therefore my questions are :

1. Is it possible to re-define the objective function to optimize XGBClassifier for discrimination power rather than probabilities ?
2. If not, what are other ways to "boost" the discrimination power of my model besides hyper-parameter optimization ?
3. Conceptually, the ability to discriminate 2 samples is close to the task of "learning to rank". Therefore, is there a way to use XGBRanker for standard classification ? Have you tried it ?

PS : Don't think it is important here but mentioning it just in case : I actually only care about partial AUC : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_Area_Under_the_ROC_Curve
because areas where the False Positive Rate is too high (say above 20%) is not applicable in my case.

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Interesting question (+1), most of what you ask for is definitely doable. Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, we can consider using `binary:hinge` as our objective such that we  get 0/1 predictions.
2. Using a custom evaluation metric is straightforward in XGBoost (a custom objective function is a  bit thornier as it requires a Hessian), there is a nice worked example in the [Custom Objective and Evaluation Metric](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html#customized-metric-function) section so defining Partial AUC-ROC should be easy. Note that [`sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) has an argument for partial AUC calculations already so that might save you even more coding. Just note that we need to set `disable_default_eval_metric` to `True` so we use primarily our own metric.
3. Using rankers for fraud detection definitely can be done. Nevertheless, I have not seen it in Kaggle Fraud detection competitions yet so I am not sure how easy is to implement and if it's worth the effort. We would have to reshape our data quite a bit. That said, there are some publications on this for example Viola et al. (2022) [*MetaAP: a meta-tree-based ranking algorithm optimizing the average precision from imbalanced data*](https://hal.science/hal-03826066/) specifically uses XGBRanker as its baseline. Almendra (2013) [*Finding the needle: A risk-based ranking of product listings at online auction sites for non-delivery fraud prediction*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417413001437) covers a similar area too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

1. Having 0/1 predictions is actually not good for me, because I want to be able to choose a threshold (trade-off between risk and revenue). So my quest for a "discrimination boosting" objective still holds !
2. Yes, but this eval metric can only be used to optimize hyper-parameters not as part of the model training itself. As far as I'm concerned hyper-param optim has never allowed me to enhance significantly a model's performance. Are there particular parameters to tweak for my purpose ?
3. Thanks ! I'll have a look at those papers

Comment: I might amend my answer later tonight but the things to note here are: 1. I think there is a false dichotomy between discriminative power rather than probabilities here; if as you say you want to "choose a threshold (trade-off between risk and revenue)" then we want the probabilities. 2. Unless we have first and second derivates for the costs we cannot define an objective. Indeed the metric drives the hyperparameters choice but this is what is supposed to do. You can always define an objective with a hyperparameter itself (as for example the`roc_auc_score` mentioned)